# Решил решить задачку по математике с помощью C++

Tags: c++

Нужно найти наименьшее натуральное число, которое при делении на 5 даёт остаток 2, при делении на 6 дает остаток 3, а при делении на 7 даёт остаток 4.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int const SIZE = 1000;
    int arr[SIZE];
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
        if (arr[i] % 5 == 2 && arr[i] % 6 == 3 && arr[i] % 7 == 4);
        {
            x++;
        }
    }
        cout << x << endl;
}
```

Вот что пока написал. За x он мне выдает последний элемент массива. Не знаю так же как реализовать программу так, чтобы он останавливал подбирать числа на наименьшем, которое подходит по параметрам

Comment: Зачем тут вообще массив? Ты с ним кроме заполнения ничего не делаешь. Просто проверяй каждое число от 7 до результата в цикле do..while (например).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, раз математическая...

```
int x = 17;
while ((x % 6 != 3) || (x % 7 != 4))
    x += 5;
cout << x ;
```

Ваша программа просто инкрементировала число. Что пишете, то и получаете...

Comment: А почему начинаем с 17  и прибавляем по 5?

Comment: потому что, все числа, делящийся на 5,  заканчиваются на 0 или 5, а  чтобы иостаток был равен 2, нужно добавить 2. Числа 7 и 12 точно не подходят нам...

Comment: прибавляем по 5, чтобы число делилось на 5 с остатком 2